# Unable to ssh from one Google Cloud RedHat/CentOS server to another

Tags: centos, ssh, rhel, google-cloud

I have created 2 Google Compute servers using Google Cloud.
Both are RedHat. (I tried using CentOS as well.)

Google by default creates a default user on both the servers.
The default user name is `gtest1`. It is letting me login to both these servers using `gtest1`.

What I'm trying to do is this:

1. I logged into server1 using `gtest1` (Success)
2. I logged into server2 using `gtest2` (Success)
3. I created a new user on server2 - username: `test2`

BUT now when I try to login to server2 from server1 using ssh test2@server2 it is giving me below error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

I checked the logs on server2. It says that connection closed by server1.
That means, something is wrong at the source server.

- When I try to do ssh server2 from server1 - it works
- When I try to do ssh test2@server2 - it throws above error.

I'm not sure why it's not letting me enter the password.

This started like 1.5 months back. Since then I couldn't work on any of my projects using Google Cloud compute instances.

There was a time I was having 25 redhat/centos servers and I used to create/delete/ssh from these servers without any issues. I'm a linux admin - but I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Anyone - any thoughts?

Comment: Please review your question to remove the confusing amount of accounts you created all over the place and the centuries of experience you have, and replace it with the specific troubleshooting you attempted, including the answer from Danduk82 if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error simply because you do not provide a valid ssh-key (publickey) and no gssapi key neither.

In general it is a bad idea to allow password login (very week security). But if you really want, just add `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then restart sshd with

```
service restart sshd
```

edit:
you really should use ssh keys

Comment: It is not getting blocked at the destination server. It is getting blocked at the source server.

Comment: Could you try to run `ssh -vvv  test2@server2` and post the output as edit of your question? (please obfuscate any IP or DNS name, as a best practice)

Comment: @wiseone why do you think it's the client that's blocking your `ssh` connection? From what you've written in your question it seems highly likely that it's the server rejecting the request.

Comment: You guys were right. It was getting blocked at the destination server. 
I had to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and then turn ON password authentication.